Integral of a Generalized Laguerre Polynomial
I am looking for the solutions to the following integral:
$$
I_{n} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{4}
\operatorname{L}_{n}^{3}\left(x\right)
{\rm e}^{-\left(n + 3\right)x/2}\,{\rm d}x,\qquad n \in\mathbb{N}_{0}
$$
where $\operatorname{L}_{n}^{3}\left(x\right)$ denotes a Generalized Laguerre Polynomial.

I believe there has to be a simple trick, similar to the orthogonality relations, but I can't find it.
The first few terms are:
$$
I_{n} = \left\{\frac{256}{81},\frac{9}{8},\frac{9216}{15625},\frac{800}{2187},\cdots\right\},\quad\mbox{for}\
n = 0,1,2,3,\ldots
$$

Can anyone help me find a closed form for any $n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ ?.

$$I_n=\frac{128 \left((n+1) (n+2) , _2F_1\left(5,-n;4;\frac{2}{n+3}\right)\right)}{(n+3)^4}$$

Better
$$I_n=\frac{64 (n+1) (n+2)^2 \left(1-\frac{2}{n+3}\right)^{n-1}}{(n+3)^5}$$
See WolframAlpha

Thanks a lot! I belive the answer I posted below is equivalent.

I found the following solution myself a little later:
$$
I_n = 2^6\frac{(n+2)^2}{(n+3)^4}\bigg(\frac{n+1}{n+3}\bigg)^n
$$

Generated in Mathematica. Generalization:
$$\int_0^{\infty } x^m L_n^{\alpha }(x) \exp (-(a n+b) c x) \, dx=\\\frac{c^{-1-m} (b+a n)^{-1-m} \Gamma (1+m) \Gamma (1+n+\alpha ) \,
   _2F_1\left(1+m,-n;1+\alpha ;\frac{1}{b c+a c n}\right)}{\Gamma (1+n) \Gamma (1+\alpha )}$$

Thank you! Very helpful!
